# Storing array as an object to be used by other functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding the possibility of exporting arrays:

Problem: A worksheet is filled with data wihch I would like to use not only for this worksheet for any other worksheet. Thus, my idea was to store the values in an array (which works) and then export the array into some sort of an object (a library?) that I can just load via VBA. After loading, the values would just be stored in VBA, there is no need to display them.

Goal: The goal is to be able to load this "library" via VBA

I've alreay created the array that I need with the needed dimensions.

```
Public Sub loadArray()
Dim myArr As Variant
    Worksheets("test").Activate
    myArr = Range("B34:I42")

End Sub
```

Comment: Look for static variables. Maybe it could help for what you’re looking for

Comment: @Damian: Feel free to post an answer. I deleted mine :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout nah... He might even want to store the array for different procedures not linked, so I would tell him to store the array everytime in that case. He is using it only to calculate things from it, as for his question he doesn't want to change the original sheet so there is no need in my opinion to store the array 1 time only.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I'm not familiar with static variables, but don't those lose their values as the workbook is closed? I have a feeling OP may want to have values permanently stored in VBA, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Please provide more specific info. Do you want to save the data from that sheet to a file and load to from file after reopening workbook? How do you want to use the data from that sheet for any other worksheet?

Comment: I would like to add that the line `Worksheets("test").Activate` could best be omitted and that you should use `myArr = Worksheets("test").Range("B34:I42")` instead

Comment: If the data is already stored in a sheet, you could just `Query` the sheet for your data. You don't necessarily need to open the workbook. Have a look at: **how to query an excel file**

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answer!                                                             
@omegastrips: The data from sheet "test" shall be stored in an external file (for example a csv) so that, after clicking on a speciic macro, the information can be retrieved automatically from that csv and populate an array with it. Why do I want to do this: Because I don't want to copy the database I have in Excel into vba :).